# Using same hibernate mapping files across multiple projects

Tags: java, hibernate

There are several java SE apps using the same library and working with the same database via Hibernate (not JPA). Where do I put hibernate mapping files and hibernate config? (so what can be extracted to the library?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put everything that is common to all applications in the library, and everything related to a specific application (database URL, user, password, but maybe also caching options, etc.)  outside of the library.

At then end, everything is loaded from the classpath. Whether the files are in one jar or another doesn't matter for Hibernate.

If you use annotations, most of the configuration will be in the entity classes anyway.

Comment: I don't use annotations, hbm-files seems to be enough to fit all the needs. So you say I better put all hbm files into the library? To the default package or where?

Comment: I prefer putting the hbm.xml file of an entity in the package of the entity, as shown in the example config file in the doc: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#tutorial-firstapp-configuration. But it doesn't matter, as soon as the path is the correct one in the main config file.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider extracting all those mapping into single "DAO" project. Then you might add "DAO" dependency to all your apps. This way only "DAO" would communicate with DB and only "DAO" will require such mapping files.