# Hibernate one to one mapping issue

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to creating java web application which depends on several java projects. I need to refer to DTO class in another project, for hibernate mapping file. But while running the application with tomcat, I get `persistent class not known:` exception.

My DTO and hbm file structure in projects are like following,

1. common-api/java/src/com/test1/dto/Manager.java (package - com.test1.dto)

   common-api/java/config/hibernate/manager.hbm.xml
2. new-api/java/src/com/test2/dto/Depeartment.java (package - com.test2.dto)

   new-api/java/config/hibernate/department.hbm.xml

Department DTO classes has a Manager objec as a property.

```
public Class Department {
    private Manager manager;
}
```

Department hibernate mapping file contains,

```
<hibernate-mapping>

<class name="com.test2.dto.Department" table="department">

    <id name="id" column="id" type="integer">
        <generator class="increment" />
    </id>

    ...

    <one-to-one name="manager" class="com.test1.dto.Manager" cascade="save-update" >
    </one-to-one>

</class>
```

Seems the class attribute value is not resolved by hibernate. It's highly appreciate if you guys can suggest me what I can do for this ?

Comment: check the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7951075/using-same-hibernate-mapping-files-across-multiple-projects

Answer (score 1):

Just include all mapping files in your top level `hibernate.cfg.xml` , eg:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory ... >
    <mapping resource="org/hibernate/auction/Item.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/hibernate/auction/Bid.hbm.xml"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-xmlconfig